# My list is empty but I can't figure out why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner and am making a grocery list of sorts for a school project using Python 3 with the use of a text file where you can choose one of the items by code. The items you choose will therefore go into a separate list and later is supposed to get printed out. The problem is that my list where the user get to choose is empty and I don't really know what to do.

```
def listInsert(item_code, quantity):
    item_code = input("What item do you want? ")  
    while koden != "#":
        quantity = input("How many do you want? ")
        valda_varor.append(item_code)
        antalen.append(quantity)
        print("The item is in your bag")
        koden = input("Do you want anything more, write # if not") 
    else:
        val2 = input("Write # to end")
    return item_code  
    return quantity


def köpa(krävs):
    print("Choose your items with the help of your code, write # to end and 1 to continue")
    item_code = []
    quantity = []
    while True:
        val2 = input("What do you want to do?")
        if val2 == "1":
            listInsert(item_code, quantity)
        else:
            print("bye")
            break
    return item_code
    return quantity
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The second return statement in each of your functions is unreachable, because the previous return ends the function.

Comment: You pass lists into `listInsert`, but that function doesn't them; it just sets the variables to something else.

Comment: btw - you shouldn't use äöü in your code, cause other languages don't have those signs...
Not sure what you plan to do - however you don't append items to the empty lists...
As already pointed out there are several mistakes in your code

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

First your second return statement in both of your functions is unreachable as explained by khelwood.

Second, you passed your list into `listInsert` but you're not doing anything with them. You then assigned the variable `item_code` and `quantity` to get user input which means the reference to your list passed to your function is gone.

Third, you seemed to have two global list variables in `valda_varor` and `antalen` but they do not get used anywhere else. Perhaps you meant to use those lists instead since since user input value actually gets appended to these lists.

Next, when you called `listInsert`, your return value isn't used anywhere. If you want to use the return value of a function you have to assign the function calling to a variable.

`x=listInsert(item_code, quantity) #your return value from the function is assigned to x variable`

Finally, your list is empty because you just returned the empty list created earlier in the function. You did not modify the list in any way.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many problems with your code to list.  I corrected them to get the code to work the way I think you intended.  There are redundancies in this code that can be eliminated, but I kept them to replicate what you were trying to achieve. A few important points:

1. If you plan to assign responses from user to certain variables, you don't need to also put those variables in the function argument.
2. You can not put 2 return statements in a row. The first one will terminate the code.  You probably wanted to print rather than return.
3. You can't append items to lists you haven't already created.  You need to declare and initialize your two lists as empty lists before your loop.

Study this code carefully and learn from it:

```
def listInsert():
    koden = "y"
    valda_varor = []
    antalen = []
    while koden != "n":
        item_code = input("What item do you want? ")
        quantity = input("How many do you want? ")
        valda_varor.append(item_code)
        antalen.append(quantity)
        print("The item is in your bag")
        koden = input("Do you want anything more? Write y or n: ")

    for i in range(len(valda_varor)):
        print(f'You bought {antalen[i]} of item {valda_varor[i]}')


def köpa():
    print("Choose your items with the help of your code.")
    while True:
        response = input("Do you want to buy? Write y or n: ")
        if response == "y":
            listInsert()
        else:
            print("bye")
            break

köpa() #starts running the code
```